# psycopg2 db connection errors

Tags: python, psycopg2

i'm trying to connect my postgres db using the following :

```
       conn_string = "host='10.10.1.20' dbname='web' user='" + db_user + "' password='" + db_pass + "'"
       logger.info('Connecting to database -> %s' % (conn_string))
       conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
```

i'm passing the correct cred's tested it manully and its connected and i can execute query but  via psycopg2.connect i keep getting

```
Could not connect to the dababase,  name 'cur' is not defined
```

what did i missed here

Comment: Why not try to search for ```cur```, where is it in your code? if you find it replace with the cursor.

Comment: thats fixed the issue thank